# Create Symfony Entity FormType - Where to override value creation?

Tags: forms, symfony

I am working with Symfony 2.7 and I have created a custom **FormType** with parent type `'entity'` / `EntityType`.

Depending on wether the FormType is used in single or multiple mode (`$options['multiple'] == true`, both works well), the `data` property is either a single entity object or an array of entity objects. The `value` property however is automatically translated into the entities `Id` property or an array of Ids (UUIDs in my case).

Example:

```
class MyEntity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="guid", type="guid", unique=true)
     */
    protected $guid;

    ...
}
```

Passing a `MyEntity` object with `guid = abc` to the FormType will set the `data` property to this object and the `value` property to `abc`.

Passing an array of `MyEntity` object to the FormType will set the `data` property to this array and the `value` property to an array of the guids, eg. `{'abc', '123'}`.

**Question is: Where does this conversion MyEntity -> guid happen and how can I override it?**

I would like to make the FormType more flexible and allow not only `MyEntity` objects and array of `MyEntity` as input but also guids and array of guids. The Form Type receives guids instead of entities, it should automatically load the entities using the guids.

Problem is, that the conversion MyEntity -> guid already happend when `buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)` is called. Thus I had no chance to translate guids into entities first.

**What is the right place to override/intercept the the conversion to add my own guid to entity translation?**

Comment: The choice value is set [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/DoctrineChoiceLoader.php)

Comment: I think you should work with a basic ChoiceType instead of the EntityType.